I'm trying to make a small x86 program that gets as input the absolute path of a folder, which contains .txt files, and prints their size and fd
.data
    formatString: .asciz "%s"
    descLabel: .asciz "File Descriptor: %d\n"
    sizeLabel: .asciz "File Size: %d kilobytes\n\n"
    afis_nr: .asciz "%d \n"

    # Buffers and variables
    path: .space 256
    dirPtr: .space 4 # pointer to DIR structure
    dirEntryPtr: .space 4 # pointer to dirent structure

.text
CONCRETE:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    leal path, %edi # address of the path buffer
    pushl %edi
    call opendir
    addl $4, %esp
    movl %eax, dirPtr

read_dir:
    movl dirPtr, %edi
    pushl %edi
    call readdir
    addl $4, %esp
    testl %eax, %eax # check if null
    je close_dir
    movl %eax, dirEntryPtr # save dirent* pointer

    # get the d_name field of dirent
    movl dirEntryPtr, %edi
    addl $11, %edi # address of d_name in dirent

    pushl %edi # open the file using d_name
    call open
    addl $4, %esp
    movl %eax, %ebx # save file descriptor


    pushl %ebx # print file descriptor
    pushl $descLabel
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp

    # get file size with lseek
    movl $8, %eax
    movl %ebx, %edi # file descriptor
    xorl %esi, %esi # offset
    movl $2, %edx # SEEK_END
    int $0x80
    movl %eax, %ecx # save file size

    addl $1023, %ecx # calculate file size in kilobytes
    shrl $10, %ecx # divide by 1024

    pushl %ecx # print file size
    pushl $sizeLabel
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp

    movl $3, %eax # syscall: close
    movl %ebx, %edi
    int $0x80

    jmp read_dir

close_dir:
    movl dirPtr, %edi
    pushl %edi
    call closedir
    addl $4, %esp

exit_CONCRETE:
    popl %ebp
    ret

.global main
main:
    pushl $path
    pushl $formatString
    call scanf
    addl $8, %esp

    call CONCRETE

    movl $1, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80

I want to have the code print the file descriptor and size (in kilobytes), but for a folder that is given as "input" with 16 .txt files, I get 18 outputs, 16 of them having the descriptor return with -1, and the size not being calculated properly; I'm very new to assembly languages, so I suppose there must be something wrong with the offset?
    # get the d_name field of dirent
    movl dirEntryPtr, %edi
    addl $11, %edi # address of d_name in dirent

maybe something wrong here?

I see at least three problems:

The paths you get from readdir are relative to the directory you called readdir on, but the paths you pass to open need to be relative to the current directory.
You're using the syscall numbers from x86_64 even though you're targeting 32-bit x86.
Your code runs on both files and directories, but lseek on a directory isn't a valid way of getting its size.


about the first problem, I don't really understand how I should pass those paths to open, and about the 3rd, what other function could work?

@matei_piratul: The easiest thing to do for (1) is use openat and/or fstatat which take paths relative to a dirfd, which you already have open for readdir.  Otherwise you'd have to manually do string concatenation into a tmp buffer.  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/openat.2.html / https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).  opeant(dirfd, rel_path, flags) or statat(dirfd, rel_path, &statbuf, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW).  To get a directory's size, just keep reading until readdir stops returning more entries.  You only need to open subdirectories; stat gives you file sizes.
